Why MDI2 is inverted in RJ45?
I am struggling with connecting Ethernet Gigabit to a board. Despite the weird order of the pairs, the two standards (T568A and T568B) I have question related to MDI2 pair.
I notice the plain color cables are negative for all pairs, except for BI-DC where it is the opposite.

(https://allpinouts.org/pinouts/connectors/networking/ethernet-1000base-t-gigabit/)
If we take a look at the Raspberry CM5 carrier board, we notice the polarity is not reversed.

(https://www.pi-shop.ch/downloads/dl/file/id/1525/product/3068/cm5_io_board.pdf)

Looks to me like it's pair C that doesn't match.

@Hearth Thanks, I fix the question

Also, please mention the source of the table you've copied into your question; image sources are mandatory here. A link to the "raspberry CM5 carrier board" would also be required.

That table's use of "transceive" where it appears to mean "transmit" doesn't exactly inspire confidence.

As you see from the pin name table, it's not the polarity that's reversed, it's just the color of the wires that are reversed in relation to how Gigabit Ethernet uses the pinout and wire colours.
So on the table and RPi CM5 board, positive signals are on modular jack pins 1, 3, 4, and 7.
The wire colour allocation makes sure that you always have positive (tip) and negative (ring) alternating if used for four phone lines. So the order of colours in relation to polarity and usage predates TIA-568 and predates gigabit ethernet too. That mapping of colours to connector pins cannot be changed if you want to be backwards compatible and standard compliant.
But when designing new equipment, you can freely choose how you use the pins.
So Gigabit Ethernet chose to use those 8P8C pins in that way regardless of wire colour, as wire colour does not matter. All that matters is that the pairs are used correctly and that wires are connected correctly.
And since 1000Base-T has nothing to do with telephones, it can freely ignore the traditional usage of tip/ring polarity.

This doesn't answer why it's the reverse of the other two (which may even be a mistake in the source you got this table from; I don't work with ethernet often enough for it to come up), but here's why it doesn't actually matter:
For 100BASE-T, polarity is irrelevant; only the timing of transitions matters for the signalling. For 1000BASE-TX, polarity matters, but all transceivers are required to automatically detect and correct any reversed polarity, so again it effectively doesn't matter. Only in 10BASE-T is a polarity reversal potentially an issue, as the encoding used is polarity sensitive and to my knowledge the IEEE 802.3 standard has no requirement that polarity reversal be compensated for--but from what I can find, just about every 10BASE-T device auto-corrects polarity anyway, so perhaps it was a de facto standard if not a de jure standard. And besides, the third pair isn't used for 10BASE-T; it only uses the A and B pairs.
I'm not sure about the modern faster ethernet standards (2.5GBASE-T, 5GBASE-T, 10GBASE-T, 25GBASE-T, and 40GBASE-T), but I would expect the same requirement as 1000BASE-T applies.

IEEE Std 802.2-2022 section 113.1.4 Signaling for 25GBASE-T and 40GBASE-T contains The signaling scheme achieves a number of objectives including: i) Ability to automatically detect and correct for pair swapping and crossover connections. j) Ability to automatically detect and correct for incorrect polarity in the connections.. Therefore, the modern faster Ethernet standards do require the correction for reversed polarity, albeit I didn't check the sections of the standard for 2.5GBASE-T, 5GBASE-T and 10GBASE-T.
